# group plots by multiple fields

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I'm re-learning ggplot and I've got what I think is a tricky grouping questions

```
SamplePeriod=c(rep(1:2, each=6, len=12))
Market=c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=3, len=12))
Day=c(rep(1:3,len=12))
Sales=c(5,6,7,8,9,7,5,6,7,5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(Sales=as.numeric(Sales),Day=as.numeric(Day),
             SamplePeriod=as.numeric(SamplePeriod),Market)

df
   Sales Day SamplePeriod Market
1      5   1            1      A
2      6   2            1      A
3      7   3            1      A
4      8   1            1      B
5      9   2            1      B
6      7   3            1      B
7      5   1            2      A
8      6   2            2      A
9      7   3            2      A
10     5   1            2      B
11     6   2            2      B
12     7   3            2      B
```

I'd like to plot sales as a function of day. Each SamplePeriod-Market combination should be it's own line (one line for 1-A, one for 1-B, 2-A, 2-B).  Finally, I'd like to color markets differently and plot everything on one plot.

It would be useful to know how to facet each market on its own plot as well.

If anyone sees anything egregious in my generating R code as well, criticism is welcome!

Comment: You can use `interaction` to combine SamplePeriod and Market together and later facet by `~ Market`

Comment: Try `library(tidyr);library(dplyr);df %>% unite(PeriodMarket, SamplePeriod, Market) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=Sales, colour=PeriodMarket))+geom_line()+facet_wrap(~PeriodMarket)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this, is by using `facet_grid`. The following code will give you a facetted plot with a facet for each `SamplePeriod`-`Market` combination with coloured lines for each `Market`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Day, y = Sales, color = Market)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  facet_grid(SamplePeriod ~ Market, labeller = label_both) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives the following plot:

[image]

---

As @drmariod mentioned, you can use this in combination with `interaction`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Day, y=Sales, color=interaction(Market,SamplePeriod))) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  facet_grid(SamplePeriod ~ Market, labeller = label_both) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys; the interaction() was what was missing!